# "Failed to connect (window) outlet from (NSObject) to (NSWindow): missing setter or instance variable"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opengl

I'm attempting to make a triangle with Xcode

I'm entirely new to this field of code, and I don't know how any of this code works, so if you can, explain it to me like a 5yr old.

I can't find where the error originates, but honestly I don't know where to look.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error is related to the storyboard or xib. The `window` outlet of some object (a window contoller?) is connected to a window. At runtime this object (file's owner?) isn't the class specified in the storyboard/xib and the `window` outlet can't be connected. We will help you solve the problem if you edit the question and post the window related code and tell us how the `window` outlet is connected in the storyboard or xib.

Comment: Im not entirely certain what part of the code you need, as I don't yet fully understand how objective-c works. Can you guide me to what code you need?

Comment: I need to know how to reproduce the issue. What changes did you make that caused the issue? Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project?

Comment: i just followed a tutorial on how to make a window and triangle. I didn't change anything from the tutorial. Would it be better if I just sent you the whole program?

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial?

Comment: It isn't a website. You have to download it.

Comment: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window

Comment: This website directs you to the download page of the "source package" -

Comment: https://www.glfw.org/download.html

Comment: How is the `NSWindow` created?